# Cannot put text area as an option in my drop down form

Tags: html, forms, textarea

im trying to make a text area as one of my options for this form, but it is not working.

[image: Failed Result]

[image: Code]

Please do help if able to because this is an overdue assignment

Comment: Please don't share images of your code. Just copy the code into the post itself.

Answer (score 0):

The only permitted content of the `<option>` element is text unfortunately ([see MDN reference here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)).

However, if what you want is some kind of text input field that supports pre-selected options as well as custom text input, the `<datalink>` element is a built-in option:

```html
<label for="favourite-colour">Choose your favourite colour:</label>
<input list="favourite-colour" id="colour-choice" name="colour-choice">

<datalist id="favourite-colour">
    <option value="red">
    <option value="green">
    <option value="blue">
</datalist>
```

Hope this helps.